# Styling a nested table not working in IE 11

Tags: html, css

I want to style the selected css element "readonly".

[image: CSS Style]

My style

```
table.fields .readOnly {
    background-color: #e5f1f5;
}
```

doesn't work in this case. I cannot style all readonly. I need to style only the readonly within this table.

Comment: Can you give some background as to how this table is generated? Can you edit the HTML? Is it only sub-tables that you want the style on?

Comment: Yes only the sub tables. Or actually speaking sub-sub-tables. Code generated dynamically

Comment: If sub tables, and they all class of `fields` then just do `table.fields  table.fields .readOnly`

Comment: @JamieBarker nah. that's not working.

Comment: I don't know what was the issue but got it working by writing style for table.fields td.fullHeight table.fields tr td